# Telerik RadTextbox input behaving like watermark

Tags: telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-5, radtextbox

I've a Telerik RadTextbox in one of my .ascx files in a Sitefinity 5.4 website. When a form containing the RadTextbox is submitted and there is some error thrown by the server, and the user goes back and tries to resubmit the form, there is validation message appearing even if there is input showing from the initial submission. It looks like the input from the first submission is treated as watermark.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is the user going back by using the browser back button? Then the validations will still exist. Try to eliminate the errors by clients side validation first, then server side validations. If the errors still exists, you should clear the validation messages on the load of the control (if it is not a postback of course)